# 自分自身にクローズ投票をした場合に表示される通知の動作に違和感がある

Tags: バグ, 完了

### 不具合事象

以前投稿した質問が重複質問であったことに気づいたため、自分自身でクローズ投票を行いました。

- [https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3065/未ログイン時に表示されるボックスの文章が英語版と一致していない](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3065/%E6%9C%AA%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E6%99%82%E3%81%AB%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E3%83%9C%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9%E3%81%AE%E6%96%87%E7%AB%A0%E3%81%8C%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E%E7%89%88%E3%81%A8%E4%B8%80%E8%87%B4%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84) ([Web アーカイブ](https://web.archive.org/web/20200109171432/https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3065/%E6%9C%AA%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E6%99%82%E3%81%AB%E8%A1%A8%E7%A4%BA%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E3%83%9C%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9%E3%81%AE%E6%96%87%E7%AB%A0%E3%81%8C%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E%E7%89%88%E3%81%A8%E4%B8%80%E8%87%B4%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%84%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84))
  問題が解消されたため、当該投稿は削除済みです。

すると、以下の画像のメッセージが表示されますが、ここに含まれている「送信」ボタンは**クリックしても何の変化も起きません**。また、「あなたの質問の回答に当てはまりますか？」と書かれていますが、**重複候補とされる質問が表示されていません**。

もし誰がクローズ票を入れたのかによって動作が変わるのであれば、それに即した通知文に変更する必要があると思います。「送信」ボタンについても、もしクリックしても何も反応がない動作が正常なものだとしても、何が起きたのかがわかりづらいので、何かしらのメッセージを表示するとより良いと思います。

### 再現状況

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 参考までに、MSEでの [こちらの質問](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340297) に貼られている [スクリーンショット](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fu9la.png) で正常動作時の表示が確認できます。

Comment: MSEに [関連のバグ報告](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340864) が既に挙がっていました。また、別投稿の[こちらのコメント](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339700/new-post-notices-are-live-network-wide/339805#comment1135460_339805) によれば、クローズ票が十分集まっていない場合に発生しているのかも？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

この問題は解決されました。詳細については、この投稿をご覧ください。

[Nothing happens when I press "Submit" on duplicate suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340864/51)

Answer (score 3):

- いわゆる "新しい通知" は今回の例なら「あなたの」と出ている通り、ページを表示しているユーザーに応じて結果が変わるようになっています。本来なら提案された重複候補のリストが表示されるものと思いますが、第三者視点で実際の表示を確認するのは難しいかもしれません。

  もう少し詳しい情報が集まり次第、MSEにバグ報告した方が対応は早そうです。
  (セルフ投票時のみのバグ？ or 重複の提案そのものがSOjaで正常に機能していない？辺り)
- 自分自身で重複と気づいた場合には、クローズ票を入れるよりもどちらか一方の質問に情報を集約して、不要な方は削除することも検討してください。
- 通知の翻訳に違和感があったので先ほど更新しました。

  > (コミュニティメンバーが) ×類似の質問をしました / ○類似の質問を提案しています

Comment: 仰るとおり、現状有効な回答もない状態だったので、削除で済むことでした...。再現出来ている状況を手元に残しておきたいので、質問文に載せた質問の削除はもう少し時間が経ってから行おうと思います。